# Can upload file with fileupload control but cannot access file

Tags: asp.net

I can upload file (source below The file is uploaded I checked with rdp.) but I cannot access it in browser (.docx): file or directory not found. what should I do

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user configured as the app pool identity has write permissions at the location you're trying to upload to.  In this case, it looks like that is the site root.

Comment: The file is uploaded I checked with rdp.

Answer (score 1):

Log into the server via FTP or RDP to determine that the file actually exists.

If the file physically exists on the server, check IIS.  It is possible that it has not been configured to serve .docx files.

If the file doesn't exist on the server, then you most likely have an upload problem, most likely permissions.  You're trying to write files into the root directory of your website.  Even if the permissions are setup to allow that, really not a good idea.

If it is an upload problem, create a subdirectory off your root, and give the user that is running the web site modify/write permissions on that subdirectory.

Comment: I checked with rdp, file exists. As you suggest I checked mime. Is it normal that I have mime type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document for .docx ? What should it be instead ?

Answer (score 1):

> I can upload file (source below) 
>   Which means you can write into the file path.
>
> I cannot access it in browser 
>   Do you specify the right file path from your browser?
>   Do you have word installed on your client pc?

For security reason, you should put your file outside your root path. Then give it relative file path name:
"../../filename.docx" and give write and read permission to the path.